# su {user} not working inside the ssh shell on the server

Tags: server, bash, ssh, hadoop, su

I am trying to connect to the server as `root` using `ssh` command in Ubuntu bash. I use

```
ssh -p port root@ip
```

to connect to the server and the config of ssh is a password-less connection ssh with the following commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -p ""
cat /home/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/{user}/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

After connecting to the server, I run the following command:

```
su hadoop
```

It shows `hadoop@server:/root$` and after 5 secs shows `root@server ~ #`
again and every button I press on the keyboard is not typed in the bash but after pressing enter I find out that the command is done. For example if I press `ll`, nothing is shown in the terminal but as soon as I press enter, the output of `ll` is shown.

I have checked that `hadoop` user is started with bash. By the way, I have Hadoop 2.7.7 and Hbase 1.2.4 started on this very server.
I guess it is because of Hbase running on my server because as soon as I stop it after being started for a while, the problem shows up. I suggest that you should use higher versions of hbase if you have the same problem. The only reason I didn't use higher versions for hbase was to be compatibile with hadoop, but now that I read the doc more carefully, I figured out hadoop 2.7.1+ is compatible with HBase 1.3.x and 1.4.x and 2.2.x. Of course I can't still trust that.
Please help me to fix it with your ideas.

Comment: Please update your question with example of the exact code you are running.

Comment: Done! Please inform me if you need more information I can provide.

Comment: Does your `hadoop` user on the remote machine have a valid home directory? what is its login shell?. I don't really understand why you create/copy a keypair for `{user}` if you are logging in as `root` - but that seems to be an unrelated issue.

Comment: Yes it does. I can test it by `su hadoop` and then `cd ~` and its login shel is BASH.